# Applying models to multiple time-series

Tags: r, xts

Let's say I have multiple time series for which I want forecasts. If I have the appropriate time-series object for each, I could fit (for the sake of example) an ARIMA model and so on. But, I know there must be an easy way to automate this process when all of the series are in one *xts* object (leaving aside the fact that different variables might require different ARIMA models; that's probably a question for another time).

Some sample data as an xts object (daily revenue for six different businesses):

```
library(xts)

ts <- structure(c(534L, 549L, 636L, 974L, 848L, 895L, 1100L, 1278L, 
1291L, 1703L, 1532L, 533L, 619L, 642L, 939L, 703L, 759L, 1213L, 
1195L, 1153L, 1597L, 1585L, 649L, 597L, 628L, 924L, 703L, 863L, 
1261L, 1161L, 1212L, 1616L, 1643L, 583L, 694L, 611L, 891L, 730L, 
795L, 1242L, 1210L, 1159L, 1501L, 1702L, 513L, 532L, 580L, 917L, 
978L, 947L, 1227L, 1253L, 1121L, 1697L, 1569L, 646L, 636L, 516L, 
869L, 980L, 937L, 1173L, 1203L, 1204L, 1511L, 1640L), .Dim = c(11L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Americas_Globe", "Americas_Lucky", 
"Americas_Star", "Asia_Star", "EuroPac_Globe", "EuroPac_Lucky"
)), index = structure(c(1367384400, 1367470800, 1367557200, 1367643600, 
1367730000, 1367816400, 1367902800, 1367989200, 1368075600, 1368162000, 
1368248400), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"))
```

I can extract one time-series from this object...

```
ts.amerglob <- ts[,1] #Extract the "Americas_Global company time-series
```

and model it however (for the sake of example, fit an ARIMA model):

```
ts.ag.arima <- arima(ts.amerglob, order=c(0,1,1))
```

and make forecasts

```
ts.ag.forecasts <- forecast.Arima(ts.ag.arima, h=5)
```

But what if I want to do this for each of the 6 companies in this *ts* object?

When fitting standard regression models, I've used by() to do something similar with subsets of the data. But applying that methodology here doesn't seem to work:

```
co.arima <- by(ts, ts[,1:6],
    function(x) arima(x, order=c(1,0,1)))
```

returns an error about sequence length:

```
error in tapply(seq_len(11L), list(INDICES = c(534L, 549L, 636L, 974L,  : 
  arguments must have same length
```

Is there any easy way to apply a time-series model to multiple time-series at once and extract relevant information? Ultimately what I'm looking to do is put the forecasts for each of these time series into one data.frame or matrix (but it would be great to be able to do the same thing with intermediate steps in the modeling process, such as *auto.arima()* output for each time-series)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `lapply` here:

```
res <- lapply(dat.ts,arima,order=c(1,0,1))
```

If you want to use different order parameter for each time serie, you can use `Map` or `mapply`:

```
## generate a random list of orders
orders <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(dat.ts)),function(x)sample(c(0,1),3,rep=T))
## for each serie compute its arima with its corresponding order
Map(function(x,ord)arima(x,ord),as.list(dat.ts),orders)
```

**EDIT** get order using auto.arima fom `forecast` package:

*Note I am rarely use this package, so I am not sure of the final result.* I show here just the idea of using `lapply`:

```
orders <- lapply(dat.ts,function(x){
             mod <- auto.arima(x)
             mod$arma[c(1, 6, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5)][1:3]
 })
$Americas_Globe
[1] 0 1 0
$Americas_Lucky
[1] 0 1 0
$Americas_Star
[1] 0 1 1
$Asia_Star
[1] 0 1 0
$EuroPac_Globe
[1] 0 1 0
$EuroPac_Lucky
[1] 0 1 0
```

Comment: This is great and exactly what I'm looking for. But now I'm running into problems if I want to do the same with forecasts from the fitted ARIMA models. It seems like I should be able to take the *res* object and use the same *lapply* method to create a matrix of forecasts, something like: lapply(res, forecast.Arima,h=5)...

Comment: Also, as a separate (related) question: Is there a way to extract the suggested ARIMA order parameters into a list via *auto.arima()*? If I were to do something like: res <- lapply(dat.ts,auto.arima) to get the list orders and use that as the final parameter in the *map* function?

Comment: Yes you can do `lapply(res, forecast.Arima,h=5)` or more explicitly `lapply(res, function(model) forecast.Arima(model,h=5))`

Comment: Yeah that's perfect! But now I'm running into the issue of: If I run the lapply ARIMA code manually, rather than using the *orders* function to map orders to each ARIMA model, I can do lapply(res, forecast.Arima) ... but if I DO use that *orders* function, it maps into the models correctly, but then gives an error when I input that mapping to the *forecast.Arima* function: "Error in ts(x) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations" ... any idea why that is? I can't find any differences between the two objects...